# How can I center a text correctly using annotation of Rmagick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

I have a problem when try to center text using annotate method of Rmagick.

I'm using Rmagick 2.13.4 and Imagemagick 6.9.0-9 on Ubuntu

You can check my code below:

```
require 'RMagick'
txt = Magick::Draw.new
txt.gravity = Magick::CenterGravity
txt.pointsize = 250
txt.undercolor = "blue"
txt.fill = "red"
image = Magick::Image.new(172, 300){
    self.background_color = 'green'
    self.gravity = Magick::CenterGravity
}
image.annotate(txt, 0,0,0,0, 'A')
image.write('A_200.jpg')
```

And the result will look like [this](http://i1065.photobucket.com/albums/u383/nvhaotl/A_200_zpstq5w2nkk.jpg)

The 'A'character deviated to right.

Here are some experiments

- The deviation depends on the font.
- The deviation depends on the first character of the string ("A" and "B" give different deviation.)
- The deviation does not depend on the length of the string ("A" and "AAA" gives same deviation)

So how can I center a text correctly using annotation of Rmagick? Thank you!

**Update**

- With txt.font = "Courier-BoldOblique"
  => The result will look like [this](http://i1065.photobucket.com/albums/u383/nvhaotl/Courier-BoldOblique_zpsl8qjvkgn.jpg)

The 'A' character deviated to left

Comment: I find it hard to see what the problem is - the `A` looks pretty central to me. Can you clarify or give a more obvious example please?

Comment: Can you try with some other fonts? When I test with `Courier-BoldOblique` font, the `A` deviated to left. You can see [here](http://i1065.photobucket.com/albums/u383/nvhaotl/Courier-BoldOblique_zpsl8qjvkgn.jpg)